# Unable to scroll due to overlay button at bottom centre screen Appium + Android

Tags: appium, ui-automation, appium-android

Code Line:

**driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains("5000666").instance(0))"));**

Even I tried to scroll to the end of the list using below code line:

**driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
"new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollToEnd(10)"));**

But this is also not working.Can any one help here with other options.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, you'll need to add an `\` to your string, like:

```
\"5000666\"
```

Your code line will be something like:

```
driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\"5000666\").instance(0))"));
```

Try it and see what happens.

The second line of code I don't know, sorry.